# Install Samsung Smart TV app

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I have developed a SAMSUNG SMART TV App in development mode. How can I install this app to client TV without using user develop?

I searched a lot in Google but I didn't get any proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is just for 2012 TV (E/ES/EH) Series:

1. Unzip your exported application to USB Drive with folder named your apps
2. Example: SampleApps_1.000_Asia_20140218.zip so resulting X:\SampleApps\config.xml
3. Plug-on the USB Drive
4. Turn off the TV
5. Turn on the TV and go to smart hub

The USB Drive "must" plugged-on when using the Apps because the apps is not installed on TV, just read from USB

Comment: It worked but when i remove the use drive then then app was also gone. Is there any to to permanent install into tv from USB Drive.

Comment: Until now i'm not finding any other method to install apps from USB. Permanent install must be done with "User Application Sync" on TV develop mode

Answer (score 2):

This will not work for 2013 TVs as they require a particular signature file generated from Samsung HQ itself.